# Google Sheets IMPORTHTML "Could not fetch data"

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to figure out why all of a sudden my importhtml links are not working anymore and they say "Could not fetch data from url".

Here the link to the site https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/split.fcgi?id=wheelza01&year=Career&t=p

On that site scroll down to 'Batting Order Positions' and then im trying to just pull tOPS+ data. Is there any way i can use XML? I was just using the link in the embed table for importhtml and it was working before

Any help much appreciated

Comment: this comes up often, companies are free to change their websites as they see fit, likely they are generating their page via javascript. So, the only option is json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data are masked by

```
<!-- ... -->
```

, nevertheless you can retrieve them by this way

```
=importxml(A1,"//div[@class='table_wrapper setup_commented commented']")
```

assuming in A1 you have your url. If you only need 'Batting Order Positions', then try

```
=query(importxml(A1,"//div[@class='table_wrapper setup_commented commented']"),"select Col3 where Col3 contains 'Batting Order Positions' ")
```

Then you have to split the response to get a clean table.

[image]

Comment: Would i be able to just pull Player Names & tOPS+?

Answer (score 1):

the site you are trying to scrape undergo "JS modernization" and google sheets cant import JavaScript elements. you can test this like:

[image]

and see that values you try to import are not present

Comment: Ohh ok. Where would i start to learn how to scrape data or what options do i have

Comment: @DavidR you would need to find another non-JS site that hosts the same data you wish to scrape